# SQL Server - Give a Login Permission for Read Access to All Existing and Future Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, sql-server-2008, roles

I have a stored procedure that finds all the existing databases and reads from a table in each one.

Is there a way I can give a login read access to all databases, and to all future databases i.e., I won't have to do anything when a new database is added?

Is there a server role that would work? Is there a way to make a SQL agent job add the permissions on any new databases?  Or is there some other method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For new databases, add the user in the model database. This is used as the template for all new databases.

```
USE model
CREATE USER ... FROM LOGIN...
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', '...'
```

For existing databases, use sp_MSForEachDb

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDb '
 USE ?
 CREATE USER ... FROM LOGIN...  
 EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ''...''
'
```

Comment: Will the user automatically get read access after running that?

Comment: Well, you'll need to grant some rights too but they'll have DB access

Comment: How do I automate granting read rights to the tables?  Otherwise I'm kind of back where I started.

Comment: @greg: I've added permissions too

Comment: By the way, just for others who came here for SharePoint, with oddities in usernames and database names (hyphens especially), I had to modify the second query above to EXEC sp_MSForEachDb '
 USE [?]
 CREATE USER [...] FROM LOGIN [...]
 EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ''...'''

Comment: ...simply had to wrap the names in square brackets. Also, thank you so much for providing this!

Answer (score 1):

USE [master]
GO
--IF  Not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM syslogins where loginname = 'replace with Login name ')
--CREATE LOGIN [replace with Login name ] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
--GO
DECLARE    @SQL              VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(255)

DECLARE crFetch CURSOR FOR
--SELECT    NAME FROM  SYSDATABASES WHERE name  in 
--('master','model','tempdb','msdb','distribution')

SELECT   NAME FROM  SYS.DATABASES WHERE name  not in 
('master','model','tempdb','msdb','distribution')

OPEN crFetch
FETCH NEXT FROM crFetch INTO @DatabaseName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN

SET @SQL =

'USE [' + @DatabaseName + ']' + 
'if not exists (select name from sysusers where name='+ ''''+ 'replace with Login name '+ ''''+ ')' +
'CREATE USER [replace with Login name ] FOR LOGIN  [replace with Login name ]' + 
'EXEC sp_addrolemember N' + '''' + 'db_ETL' + '''' + ', N' + '''' + 'replace with Login name ' + '''' +'
'

--'EXEC sp_addrolemember N' + '''' + 'db_datareader' + '''' + ', N' + '''' + 'replace with Login name ' + '''' + 
--'if not exists(select name from sysusers where name='+ ''''+ 'db_executor'+''''+ 'and issqlrole=1)' +
--'create ROLE db_executor' + ' ' +
--'GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor' + ' ' +
--'EXEC sp_addrolemember N' + '''' + 'db_executor' + '''' + ', N' + '''' + 'replace with Login name ' + '''' +'

--PRINT @SQL

EXEC(@SQL)

FETCH NEXT FROM crFetch INTO @DatabaseName
END

CLOSE crFetch
DEALLOCATE crFetch